# How are numbers represented in binary in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, binary

I'm creating a tutorial on JavaScript, and as I deal with explaining bitwise operators, etc. How negative numbers are represented in JavaScript keep coming up.

I believe all I need to describe in my tutorial is two's complement, but do I also need to describe one's complement, or is one's complement irrelevant in JavaScript?

How about floating point numbers, positive and negative numbers, in JavaScript?

Comment: All numbers in JS use IEEE 754 64-bit floating point representation, so even `x = 4` is a float. However, bitwise operators forcefully convert a number to 32-bit integer, so `3.14 | 0` will produce `3` but also `(2 ** 31 - 1) | 0` is `2147483647` yet `(2 ** 31) | 0` is `-2147483648`.

Comment: The bit string of any float can be obtained with `Array.from(new Uint8ClampedArray(new Float64Array([ 420.69 ]).buffer), (byte) => byte.toString(2).padStart(8, "0")).join("")`. Replace `Float64Array` by `Int32Array` to inspect integers. The bytes may, however, be reversed, based on endianness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All numbers in JavaScript are floating point numbers. The representation rule for negative numbers is the same as IEEE-754.

But when you are using bitwise operators in JavaScript, The operands are converted to signed 32-bit integers automatically.

Comment: Are those 32-bit integers represented in two's complement?

Comment: @GregLafrance I believe so.